# Mschart - How to change width between bars

Tags: asp.net, mschart

I know how to change the width of the bars using PointWidth which will relatively increase the space between the bars, but I want to keep the same width of the bar while increasing the space between the bars.

```
<asp:Chart ID="chart" runat="server" Height="300px" Width="850px"
            BorderDashStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="2" BackColor="#f0f0f0" Visible="false" EnableViewState="true">
            <Legends>
                <asp:Legend TitleFont="Microsoft Sans Serif, 8pt, style=Bold" BackColor="Transparent"
                    Font="Trebuchet MS, 8.25pt, style=Bold" IsTextAutoFit="False" Enabled="False"
                    Name="Default">
                </asp:Legend>
            </Legends>
            <Series>
                <asp:Series Name="s1" Color="#4f81bd" CustomProperties="PointWidth=.6" ChartType="StackedColumn100">
                </asp:Series>
                <asp:Series Name="s2" Color="#c0504d" CustomProperties="PointWidth=.6" ChartType="StackedColumn100">
                </asp:Series>
                <asp:Series Name="s3" Color="#9bbb59" CustomProperties="PointWidth=.6" ChartType="StackedColumn100">
                </asp:Series>
            </Series>
            <ChartAreas>
                <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1" BorderDashStyle="Solid">
                    <AxisX>
                        <LabelStyle Enabled="false" />
                        <MajorTickMark Enabled="false" />
                    </AxisX>
                    <AxisY>
                        <MajorGrid Interval="10" IntervalOffset="10" />
                        <MajorTickMark Enabled="true" Interval="10" IntervalOffset="10" />
                        <LabelStyle Format="{#}%" Interval="10" IntervalOffset="10" />
                    </AxisY>
                    <Position Y="0" Height="100" Width="100" X="5"></Position>
                </asp:ChartArea>
            </ChartAreas>
        </asp:Chart>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the space between bars is dynamic and not editable. Changing the width of the chart increases the space between the bars.